# How to redirect domains to a main website? (content only, I do not want the url to change)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have some domains www.example.com (my main website), www.example.pt, www.exampleexample.com and www.exampleexample.pt. They are all wordpress websites.

I was asked to "redirect" all websites to www.example.com. The first thing I tried was:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
redirectMatch 301 ^/ http://example.pt
# END WordPress
```

And it worked but when I tried to access the www.example.pt, the URL would change to www.example.com, and we don't want that.

We want the URL not to change, but to display the same content as www.example.com on all of out websites.

We understood that google does not allow duplicated content to be displayed, so is there any solution?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Something new came up now.

So I have www.example.com and www.exampleexample.com, and they are both on the same server.
However, when I access www.exampleexample.com I am automatically redirected to www.example.com, and I don't have any redirection code on my htaccess file.

Do you know what may be causing this?**

## **SOLVED**

> define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
>   define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

Just needed to add these two lines in the wp-config file (at the beggining) and it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it all depends on your hosting setup really. If all of your domains are pointed at the same server, you should be able to point them at the data on that server. Basically, you should be able to have all of your domains pointing at one place.

For reference, I'm still setting up my new server so at the moment drunkoncaffeine.co.uk, drunkoncaffeine.com, f291.net and moltis.co.uk all point at the same website. You should also be able to set this up on purpose.

How will depend on your server setup. If each of your websites is on a separate server, or this isn't doable for some other reason, a frame redirect would work. It's old school, and it isn't ideal, but it'll work for your users accessing the site (less so for bookmarking, or for Google).

Comment: Thanks Yoda. Our websites are in the same server. Do you know how to set up the host?

Comment: That will depend entirely on your host/server. You're better off asking your hosting/server company.

Comment: Thanks again Yoda.Something new came up now.

So I have www.example.com and www.exampleexample.com, and they are both on the same server.

However, when I access www.exampleexample.com I am automatically redirected to www.example.com, and I don't have any redirection code on my htaccess file.

Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: It really is going to depend on your server setup

Comment: Hi again! The solution was as simple as adding these two lines in the wp-config file (at the beggining):define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);